# Probability problem with multiple events

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

This is is a probability problem I'm having trouble solving.

You have 2 special events that can happen every second while playing a game.
$P(Event A)$ is $\frac{1}{1,000,000}$ chance per second
$P(Event B)$ is $25\%$ more likely to happen than $P(Event A)$

What is the chance that in a period of 8 hours, you get Event A exactly twice, and Event B exactly once?

I know that:

Event B is $1.25/1,000,000=1/800,000$
I probably need to use binomial distribution.

Can you help me?

Comment: $0$.  Well, effectively $0$.  Just take event $B$....there are $3600$ seconds in an hour, so (if you assume each second is an independent chance for the event) the probability that you see $B$ exactly once in $1$ hour is $3600\times \frac 1{80}\times \left(\frac {79}{80}\right)^{3659}$ which is as close to $0$ as one might reasonably want.  Gets even more unlikey after $8$ hours.  And much more unlikely if you include the other event.

Comment: The original numbers were quite big, but I think I'll revert back to them.

Comment: Well, something seems wrong with the set up as you gave it.  You expect to see $A$ $288$ times over eight hours.  Exactly $2$ times is really not possible.

Comment: I have changed back to the original numbers.

Comment: That makes it much less likely!  The event you are describing is astronomically improbable.  For all practical purposes you can take it to be $0$.  If I were playing this game and observed what you described I would assume that I had been deceived.

Comment: I know. That is what showing off is for. :P  
But how would you calculate this?

Comment: I am writing it up and will post it soon.

Comment: OK, thank you. That would be great

Comment: Just posted it.  My intuition was wrong.  Changing your numbers the way you did made the double event in question a lot more likely. Still pretty remote though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: my intuition (as expressed in the comments) was off.  The event you want, while unlikely, is not "astronomically unlikely".

Let $p_A$ (resp. $p_B$) be the probability of seeing event $A$ (resp. $B$) in  a given second.  The problem isn't clear, but let's assume that each second is an independent trial.  That is, in any given second I might see either, both or neither of $A,B$ but I can't see $A$ or $B$ twice and seeing $A$ is independent of seeing $B$.

We compute. The probability of seeing $A$ exactly twice in $8$ hours is $$\psi_1=\binom{28800}{2}\times p_A^2\times (1-p_A)^{28798}$$

Using $p_A=10^{-6}$ we get $\psi_1=\fbox {.000402933}$.

The probability of seeing $B$ exactly once in $8$ hours is $$\psi_2=\binom{28800}{1}\times p_B\times (1-p_B)^{28799}$$

Using $p_B=1.25*10^{-6}$ we get $\psi_2=\fbox {.0347271}$

Independence tells us that the probability you want is just the product $\psi_1\times\psi_2$.  Using your values we get about $\fbox {.000014}$

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This seems a lot clearer to me now.